# Where can I get the HttpRequest object when handling a response from Angular HttpClient, for accessing Application Insights ParentID?

Tags: angular, http-headers, azure-application-insights, angular-httpclient, request-headers

I am trying to access the final request object that results from a `this.httpClient.get` (or similar) call. Ideally I would like to access that request object in the error handler of the observable, and I want to access the request headers that finally went out over the wire.

For context, I am using the `applicationinsights-web` npm package to allow us to trace calls through the various services that will get hit from this client call, and the `applicationinsights-web` library adds a header containing the ParentID to the request headers in the XmlHttpRequest call that Angular's HttpClient is built upon.

I would really like for the client to be able to access that ParentID in the case of an error response from the server (4xx, 5xx). I've scoured the Angular HttpClient docs and cannot find a mention of getting the HttpRequest from the response. I've also searched and looked through the Application Insights documentation, but there is not much of a reference of the objects within applicationinsights-web, other than through IntelliSense.

Any thoughts on this appreciated!

Comment: So you want to have access to all data of response? Headers, code status, etc?

Comment: @KamLar No, I want to access all the data of the _request_. I already know how to access the full response object.